# Adding an element to a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, optionparser

I have been trying to write a very basic **generic** bash option parser for one of my projects. The idea is as follows:

- I feed a list of command-line arguments, some of them are options
- I want to extract the options into a separate array
- I will end up with two arrays:

  - One array for arguments
  - One array for options

**NOTE: I do not care about optional options and options that take arguments. For my purposes, all options are switches.**

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
parse() {
  options=()
  arguments=()

  for arg
  do
    if [[ $arg = -* ]]
    then
      options+=("$arg")
    else
      arguments+=("$arg")
    fi
  done

  echo $options
  echo $arguments
}

# $ parse --one --two -v "FOO" "BAR"
# => --one
# => FOO
```

The problem, as you can see in the output, is that only the first option and the first argument are stored in the array.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing and storing is OK, output is wrong: you are only printing the first element of the arrays.

See "Arrays" in `man bash` for proper syntax:

```
echo "${options[@]}"
echo "${arguments[@]}"
```